# Как в Windows Server 2008 R2 настроить интернет так, чтобы остался доступ к локальным веб-приложениям по локальным доменным именам?

Tags: сеть, dns, iis, windows-server, iis-7

У меня есть простая локальная сеть из 3 виртуальных машин:
1. Windows Server 2008 R2 - контроллер домена, ADFS (adfs.test.com).

```
ip: 192.168.1.5
mask: 255.255.255.0
dns: 127.0.0.1
```

2. Windows Server 2008 R2 - iis 7.5 (iis.test.com) - веб-сервер

   ip: 192.168.1.6
   mask: 255.255.255.0
   dns: 192.168.1.5
3. Windows 7 - клиент (авторизуется под  учетной записью AD)

   ip: 192.168.1.2
   mask: 255.255.255.0
   dns: 192.168.1.5

В локальной сети всё работает отлично. 
Как сделать так, чтобы был доступ в интернет, а также остался доступ к веб-приложениям по локальным доменам?
Пытался добавить второй интерфейс, работающий через NAT. Включаю его, интернет есть, а сети нет. Также на локальном интерфейсе прописывал шлюз, та же история. Файрвол отключал, в hosts

```
192.168.1.5 adfs.test.com 
192.168.1.6 iis.test.com
```

тоже дописывал. Может в iis проблема?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно больше информации..

Непонятно как именно выдаётся интернет виртуальным мащинам.

Так как автор не оговаривает наличие proxy, то предположим что виртуалки где-то на локальном хосте, и интернет выдаётся просто прописыванием default gateway. Тогда я бы прописал маршрут на нужную подсеть через IIS.

Маршрут прописывается:
route ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0  192.168.1.5 -p

Если используется proxy - то в настройках нужно указать, что для подсети 192.168.0.0/16 proxy не использовать.

Если под гипервизором - там отдельные сети и маршрутизацию нужно прописывать там.